# How to exclude some fields from json schema

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

I am trying to generate POJO classes from JSON schema using jsonschema2pojo in java spring boot. I am using the maven plugin mode of it. I like to exclude some fields which are in the schema, but it seems this feature is not supported in the jsonschema2pojo library as per https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/966.

Any suggestion on how can I achieve this? or any other library which supports this feature?

Comment: Can't you just delete the property from the schema before you feed it into jsonschema2pojo? Or delete the unwanted field after it comes out?